# MySQL Query to get rank based on the most voted photos of an user

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count

right now I'm using this query to get the rank of the user. The problem is that it uses all the votes from all his photos to get his rank. I want the query to only use his top voted photo to calculate his rank.

Here is the original query, any help would be very very appreciated:

```
            select WrappedQuery.*
            from (
                select
                  @rownum := @rownum +1 as rank,
                  prequery.user_id,
                  prequery.vote_count
                from
                  ( select @rownum := 0 ) sqlvars,
                    ( SELECT user_id, count(id) vote_count
                      from votes
                      where theme_id = '$currentTheme->id'
                      group by user_id
                      order by count(id) desc) prequery
                  ) WrappedQuery
            where WrappedQuery.user_id = '$me->id'
```

I tried to make a LIMIT 0, 1 in the prequery but didn't work.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: you can use MAX of MySQL

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a specific photo, then ignore grouping by the person, but the specific element, THEN roll-back that information to get the user.  Your use of sqlvars @rownum principle will remain the same.

Have your inner query be more like (guessing on column name of specific "Photo_ID" would be in the table also)

```
select
       @rownum := @rownum +1 as rank,
       prequery.user_id,
       prequery.photo_ID,
       prequery.vote_count
   from
      ( select 
              v.User_ID,
              v.Photo_ID, 
              count(*) as Vote_Count
           from 
              IsItStillTheVotesTable v
           group by 
              v.User_ID,
              v.Photo_ID
           order by 
              count(*) desc ) as prequery,
      ( select @rownum := 0 ) sqlvars
   HAVING
      prequery.user_id = '$me->id'
   LIMIT 
      0,1
```

The "prequery" will already return the records in proper descending order ranked sequence.  Then, you have to apply the @rownum to all rows possible and apply a HAVING clause.  The Where clause typically pre-checks if a record qualified for the result set and throws out if not before the @rownum would get assigned.  The HAVING clause allows the record to have the @rownum get applied, THEN look at it for your "user_ID" and if not, throws it out.  This way, you'll get your rank on the specific combination of user AND specific photo.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the explanation. How ever, I can't get this to work. It returns rank = 1, as if the user was first.

Comment: @Kev, Then, just for grins, try to run the inner prequery by just user/photo and count to see if that returns the records in the expected ranking (without the sqlvars rank implementation)... to see if thats ok.

Comment: Ok finally I just needed to change group by user_id to group by photo_id in my original query. Makes sense... Sorry about this, thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Kev, the group by should be on BOTH User_ID AND Photo_ID.  The photo ID to keep each photo in its own ranking, but your final HAVING clause is looking for the records for the USER and only return that user's photos (if all), or via your LIMIT 0,1 to only get the TOP one ranked.